# TinyMCE, Ckeditor... What do you use?

Tags: wysiwyg, messaging

My company is currently building a web app of which I am the front end developer. I've been doing some research into messaging services and been recommended to look at Tinymce and Ckeditor. Both of which I have tried and am not overly keen on their functionality.

Essentially the messages sent out will need to include a signature that is unique to the user currently logged into the system as well as be able to utilize templates for marketing purposes (advertising etc).

So, the question is. Have you had any experience with alternatives? And would you recommend it based on my small requirements?

Cheers,

Comment: What are your requirements? How well do these things fit your requirements? How well do they fit in your application? That's probably your answer...

Comment: the crm we're building will basically replace outlook in the office along with some other applications that we currently use. just condensing everything basically. im sure that with experience ck and tiny are very good but for someone who hasnt used them before they can be confusing with regards to creating templates etc so im asking for alternatives